# Validate ASCII GnuPlot file with c++ regex

Tags: c++, regex, validation

I have been trying to get this right, but cannot seem to make things work the way I want it to.

I have an ASCII file containing several million lines of floating point values, seperated by spaces. Reading these values is straightforward using `std::istream_iterator<double>` but I wanted to validate the file upfront to make sure it is really formatted the way I described. Since there is only one correct format, and gazillions of way how it can be illformed, I wanted to go about it using `std::regex`.

This is what I came up with:

```
std::string begln( "^" );
std::string endln( "$" );
std::string fp( "[-+]?[0-9]*.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?." );
std::string space( "[[:space:]]{1}" );
std::regex regexp( "(" + begln + fp + space + fp + space + fp + endln + ")+" );
```

What I wanted to express was: A line consists of something between the beginning and end of the line, which consists of three sets of floating point values seperated with a single space, and I am looking for one or more of these lines.

I would expect a valid datafile to have a single match without prefix and suffix.

But hey, since these values will go into a `std::vector<std::array<double, 3>>`, why don't I reuse the regex machinery and obtain the values from a match list? If the file is valid, then an absolutely trivial regex could match just individual lines, and construct a `std::sregex_iterator` to iterate over the lines. At this point, it is only a matter of obsession how one obtains the values from a singe `std::string` of a line, whether using regex again or `std::stringsteam`.

Comment: TBH it's easier to just read it. `1.0E45649867349640978347` clearly isn't a `double`, but it passes your regex. Also, "there is only one correct format" doesn't match your actual regex.`[-+]?` tells me that a leading `+` is optional and thus `+1.0` and `1.0` are both correct formats. And so is `1.0E0` or `1.0E+0` or `1.0E00` or `01`.

Comment: I might not have been 100% mathematically correct in all aspects. The floating point regex could be a page long if I were to include the things you just mentioned, plus taking into account localization issues with the decimal point/comma, etc.

Point is, I would like to rule out things such as # leading comment lines that would result in garbage output when one tries to extract data with an 'istream_iterator<doubule>'.

Comment: That comment wouldn't cause garbage, that would cause a straightforward stream extraction failure. In fact, the stream is good if and only if all extractions so far succeeded. As for localization, understand that your suggestion means that you still have `istream_iterator<double>`. If you _also_ have a regex, you now have _two_ grammars for the same language.

Answer (score 0):

Why not? The reason why you wouldn't want this is because regex'es are absolute overkill. They can match far more complex grammars, and are capable of reading in those grammars at runtime. That flexibility comes at a high price. All the possible parsers must be included. No current compiler is smart enough to see that you just used `[[:space:]]` as a regex. (In fact, no C++ compiler or linker knows anything about regex - that's purely a library thing).

In comparison, `operator>>` is overloaded and the compiler sees exactly which overloads you use at compile time. The linker is told this, and includes just the relevant code.

Furthermore, the CPU branch predictor will soon notice that `operator>>` almost always succeeds, which is a further speedup. Your regex code is less likely to benefit in the same way - the conditional part in `[0-9]*` is at least one level of indirection deeper.

Comment: Why would regex'es be overkill? If they are used in GUI engines to validate a single text box to see if the user really entered a number when prompted for a 'year' value, then why is it overkill to validate a set of numbers in a well defined manner?

Also, [[:space:]] is valid ECMAScript extension of the C++ STL Regex library, which I have indicated that the question relates to. (Or I misunderstood your comment here)

Comment: @Meteorhead: That use would also be overkill, but runtime performance isn't that crucial: humans are even slower than regex. As for code size, the linker needs to include the code for `[[:space:]]` even though the Year check doesn't need it. The linker simply doesn't know what regex will be constructed at runtime and must assume the worst.